# jQuery Processing to iPhone Native?

Tags: jquery, iphone, cross-platform, native, processing

Is there a way to convert [processing](http://Processing.org) apps to native iPhone app's?

Alternatively... there's a nice [jQuery library for processing](http://processingjs.org/), but can that be used with the various [cross-platform "develop using HTML/JS, get a native app" conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305124/comparison-of-cross-platform-mobile-app-development-solutions-iphone-androi)

Comment: why was this question downvoted just now

Answer (score 0):

Sort version: *no*, there is no *native* app converter in existence for this.  A project like this requires a huge amount of effort, and Apple's current terms forbid this (though they have yet to *enforce* that rule AFAIK).

Basically, it just isn't popular enough to warrant this, especially when the platform itself runs decently *inside* the browser.  There's no converter or "Processing VM" out there at the moment...and I wouldn't wait for one either, this will likely never happen, since the browser itself is capable.

Comment: Speaking of Apple's current terms on third party/cross-platform conversion, what are your thoughts on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305124/comparison-of-cross-platform-mobile-app-development-solutions-iphone-androi